# Como separar array por colunas

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Boa noite!

Gostaria de pedir ajuda de voces no seguinte...

Preciso ler um txt, que contem informacoes de um cliente x...

So que esse txt esta separado por linhas e eu n posso mudar pois e um arquivo pronto de outro programa...

Preciso separar esses dados e salvar em um banco de dados... Consegui separar em partes ele... Mas fica assim:

***Array ( [0] => 000145010730634CARLOS SILVA 0000015255 ) Array ( [0] => 0001 ) Array ( [0] => 00000102534 ) Array ( [0] => CARLOS SILVA ) Array ( [0] => 152,55 )***

E eu n sei como colocar esses valores no meu banco.

Tenho esse codigo aqui:

```
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

foreach ($dados as $linha) {

    $values = explode("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", $linha);

    print_r($values);        

}
```

Este codigo me da aquele resultado...

Agora preciso colocar aqueles dados em uma tabela...

Se puderem me ajudar.

Agradeco desde ja!

Comment: Coloque uma amostra do seu ficheiro de texto

Comment: À medida que le os dados no foreach adiciona na BD

Comment: já conseguiu solucionar?